# Клик внутри балуна

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Нужно отловить клик внутри балуна по кнопке, но ничего не выходит(((
Помогите пожалуйста.

Делал так:

```
objectManager.objects.balloon.events.add('click', function (e) {

});
```

но не понял как поймать именно клик по кнопке

и делал так:

```
MyBalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
                '<div class="baloon_header mb-2">$[properties.balloonContentHeader]</div>' +
                '<div class="baloon_body mb-2">$[properties.balloonContentBody]</div>' +
                '<div class="baloon_footer mb-2">' +
                    '<div class="btn_action m-1">' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" id="details_balloon">подробнее</button > ' +
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="select_balloon">заберу отсюда</button >' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>',
                {
                    build: function () {
                        MyBalloonContentLayout.superclass.build.call(this);
                        $('#details_balloon').bind('click', this.onCounterClick);
                    },

                    clear: function () {
                        $('#details_balloon').unbind('click', this.onCounterClick);
                        MyBalloonContentLayout.superclass.clear.call(this);
                    },

                    onCounterClick: function () {
                        console.log(this.getData().geoObject);
                    }
                }),
```

а тут не понял как получить объект балуна

```
this.getData().geoObject
```

не работает.

вот мой код https://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/5o7gbcfL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.onCounterClick = this.onCounterClick.bind(this);
$('#counter-button').bind('click', this.onCounterClick);
```

Нужно просто привязать контекст к функции onCounterClick